# Получить id notification

Tags: android, уведомления, android-notification

Я создаю уведомления и при нажатии на них открываю активность. Как мне из этой активности узнать id уведомления которое вызвало его открытие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можно элементарно добавить `Extra`'ы.

Вот код запуска уведомления:

```
int id = твой id уведомления;
Intent myIntent = new Intent(...);
myIntent.putExtra("myNotificationId", id); <<< кладём твой id
myNotificationManager.notify(id, new android.app.Notification.Builder(context)
        ...
        .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, myIntent, flags)) <<< пихаем в уведомление
        ...
```

Вот код как получить из запущенной `Activity` твой id уведомления (это в метод `onCreate()`):

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("myNotificationId", 0)
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Но еще по скольку в моем случае используется MainActivity, которая в этот момент может быть уже создана, то нужно в onCreate() вызвать onNewIntent(getIntent()); , и переопределить этот метод public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {...}